# Determine who changed SharePoint View

Tags: 2013, list-view, auditing

Is there a way to determine who changed a public view in SharePoint 2013, without coding?

Comment: I tested open the view with SharePoint Designer, but the last change is not logged ...

Comment: I checked SharePoint database model and I think this data is no stored :-(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this listview modification data isn't logged in the audit or the event cache. You could, however look into the IIS logs, scanning for ViewEdit.aspx. This, at the very least, will give you some detail on who visited the page at what time